# RMarkdown: Color single cells in an HTML table based on conditions

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, r-markdown

I sucessfully generated a table in R markdown using xtable (HTML) .

[image]

Now I want to color format the 3rd column based on the values in the cell .
say highest value in red , lowest in green , and remaining in different shades. 
The values in cell are generated dynamically . Some thing like this happens in excel quite easily using conditional formatting option . Can we do this in R using css ! Any help and suggestion welcome .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery inside your RMarkdown script like this:

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Yourname"
date: "June 16, 2016"
output: html_document
---

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $td = $('#myTable tr:not(:has(th)) :nth-child(5)');
        var entries = new Array();
        $td.each(function() { 
          entries.push(parseFloat($(this).html()));
        })
        var minimum = Math.min.apply(Math, entries);
        var maximum = Math.max.apply(Math, entries);

        $("#myTable tr :nth-child(5):contains('" + minimum + "')").css('background-color', 'green');
        $("#myTable tr :nth-child(5):contains('" + maximum + "')").css('background-color', 'red');
    });
</script>

```{r, echo=F, results='asis'}
library(xtable, quietly = T)
myTable <- xtable(head(mtcars))    
print(myTable, type="html", html.table.attributes='border=1 id=myTable')
```
````

The JavaScript reads out all values of column 5 (`:nth-child(5)`, including the row names) and checks for the minimum and maximum. Afterwards it matches the cells of that column with these values and applies CSS attributes.
Notice that I specified an ID for that table (`#myTable`). So if you have multiple table, the JavaScript can select the correct one.

[image]